# How can i use if else validation in regex

Tags: regex

I know how to validate a constant string with regex, but I'm really having trouble finding out how to do the following: I want a regex to validate the string `edv_` after that I want the validation to be **dependent**:

- if the user inputs for example `edv_2`, only `6` or `7` can be the next character. So only `edv_26` or `edv_27` would be valid
- if the user would enter `edv_3` then only `edv_32` or `edv_39` would be valid

Ive tried searching on the internet watched several youtube tutorials. None of them seem to handle this kind of thing. It's always only 1 constant thing they want to validate.

```
/[e][d][v][_][A]/ig
```

This matches the first part (`edv_digit`) but I have no clue how I should continue with the if else conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need alternations for handling your various cases. You can use this regex which matches as per your criteria.

```
\bedv_(?:2[67]|3[29])\b
```

Here boundaries ensure it doesn't match partial text like `abcedv_26` or `edv_26111` and it starts matching with `edv_` then looks for either `2` followed by either `6` or `7` or looks for `3` followed by `2` or `9`.

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6rNJqz/1)**